# How to filter external JSON data and get firstName using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, api

I just want to get the data of First Name which is entered in Input field. And render the HTML of the searched name.

```
$.getJSON("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students", fetchData);


var input = `<input type="text" placeholder="Search Here">`;

function fetchData(data) {
      const profile = ` <div class="container">
      <p id="input">${input}</p>
            ${data.students
              .map(
                data =>
                  `
                  <div class="profile">
                    <img src="${data.pic}">
                      <div id="display">
                        <h1 id="name" style="font-size:50px">${data.firstName}</h1>
                        <p>Email: ${data.email}</p>
                        <p>Company: ${data.company}</p>
                        <p>Skill: ${data.skill}</p>
                        <p>Grades: ${data.grades}</p></div>
                  </div>`
              )
              .join(" ")}
              </div> </div>`;
      document.body.innerHTML = profile;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a _problem statement_.  What's working / not working? Also, this is hard to provide any answers if you don't provide some sample of your JSON/...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const allData = $.get("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students")

// Customise your search function here, perhaps use a RegEx
function match(a, b) {
  return a.toLowerCase().startsWith(b.toLowerCase())
}

// This just filters the data using the search function above
function getData(search) {
  const data = allData.responseJSON && allData.responseJSON.students || [];
  return data.reduce(
    (acc, s) => match(s.firstName, search) ? (acc || []).concat(s) : acc,
    []
  );
}

// Abstracting this into another function to keep the code clean
function renderStudent(data) {
  return `
    <div class="profile">
      <img src="${data.pic}">
      <div id="display">
        <h1 id="name" style="font-size:50px">${data.firstName}</h1>
        <p>Email: ${data.email}</p>
        <p>Company: ${data.company}</p>
        <p>Skill: ${data.skill}</p>
        <p>Grades: ${data.grades}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `;
}

// Get results when a search is made
// Could use `$('#search').on('keyup', function ...)` for better response, instead of waiting
//   for the user to press ENTER
$('#search').change(function(e) {
  $('.results').html(getData($(e.currentTarget).val()).map(renderStudent).join())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <p><input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Search Here" /></p>
  <div class="results" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a `doSearch` function to filter your search value. Maybe it's not the best practice to resolve your question, but it would give you idea to resolve the problem.

```
var myData = null;
$.getJSON("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/students", fetchData);
var input = `<input id="searchValue" type="text" placeholder="Search Here"><input type="button" value="search" onclick="doSearch()" />`;
function fetchData(data) {
    myData = data;
    renderAllHtml(data);
}
function doSearch() {
    var searchValue = $('#searchValue').val();
    if (searchValue) {
        myData.students.forEach(item=>{
            if (searchValue === item.firstName) {
                renderFilterHtml(item);
            }
        })
    }else {
        renderAllHtml(myData);
    }
}

function renderFilterHtml(data) {
    const profile = ` <div class="container"><p id="input">${input}</p>
    <div class="profile">
            <img src="${data.pic}">
              <div id="display">
                <h1 id="name" style="font-size:50px">${data.firstName}</h1>
                <p>Email: ${data.email}</p>
                <p>Company: ${data.company}</p>
                <p>Skill: ${data.skill}</p>
                <p>Grades: ${data.grades}</p></div>
          </div>
      </div> </div>`;
    document.body.innerHTML = profile;
    $('#searchValue').val(data.firstName);
}

function renderAllHtml(data) {
    const profile = ` <div class="container"><p id="input">${input}</p>
    ${data.students
        .map(
            data =>
                `
          <div class="profile">
            <img src="${data.pic}">
              <div id="display">
                <h1 id="name" style="font-size:50px">${data.firstName}</h1>
                <p>Email: ${data.email}</p>
                <p>Company: ${data.company}</p>
                <p>Skill: ${data.skill}</p>
                <p>Grades: ${data.grades}</p></div>
          </div>`
        )
        .join(" ")}
      </div> </div>`;
    document.body.innerHTML = profile;
}
```